# Backbone.js: how to handle difference between model and server response

Tags: javascript, model, backbone.js

I am writing a Backbone application, where I have no control over the entities returned by the server.

It turns out that it is convenient for me to have an internal representation of the data which is slightly different with respect to the JSON used by the server. In one direction, things are easy: I can write a `Model.parse()` method which takes as input the JSON returned by the server and returns the attributes of my object.

I am not really sure what to do in the other direction. I could not find a method that is called when my object is serialized for saving. There is `Model.toJSON()` but it does not seem to be used before the model is saved.

> How am I supposed to handle this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up - the [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html) is the best place to find answers to questions about Backbone.

Looking at the source for `Backbone.sync` you can see that the model is serialized using `JSON.stringify(model.toJSON())` (presuming you are not using `emulateJSON`) so overriding this method should achieve what you need.  I can't explain why this is not working for you without a reduced test case.

The longer answer is that to have full-control of server-client synchronisation you should write your own Backbone.sync implementation.  The method is fairly simple (see the annotated source) and you can simply wrap the original sync if you just want to make simple changes.

For example:

```
function mySyncFunction(method, model, options){
  if(method == 'create' || method == 'update'){
    options.contentType = 'application/json';
    options.data = model.serializeForServer(); //You will need to write this method
  }
  return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
}
```

To use your custom sync method just declare it as part of your model

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
  ...

  "sync": mySyncFunction,

  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using the localStorage adapter for Backbone, that does not call the toJSON method. I have manually patched it, I will also check how to push it upstream